# In Java, how would you count the occurrences of each letter in the individual columns of multiple strings?

Tags: java, string

I am not sure how to do this.

Say I have multiple strings like this, perhaps in a list.

> ABSKSNFASLKFSAF
>
> LKGEROGNDFKGDFD
>
> GKDFLGSDFLGDFSJ

I would like to count the occurrence of each letter in each column.
So the first column would be "ALG", thus occurrence of A is 1, L is 1, G is 1.
the tenth column would be "LFL", occurrence of L is 2, F is 1.
etc.

The length of strings are all the same.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
strings.add(“ABSKSNFASLKFSAF”);
strings.add(“LKGEROGNDFKGDFD”);
strings.add(“GKDFLGSDFLGDFSJ”);

List<Character> column1 = new ArrayList<Character>();
for(String s : strings)
    column1.add(s[0]);

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried to use a for-loop to iterate through each string and store each letter in a list, then count the occurrence in each list but hoping to find a better way. thanks

Comment: You seem have a history of posting a set of requirements and expecting code without having made your own attempt at solving the problem.  The Stack Overflow community expects that you make the minimum effort of trying to solve the problem yourself _and_ _then_ posting a question when you have a _specific_ problem.

Comment: Specially if you want us to help you find a better way you need to show us first what way you do it now with your code.

Comment: You are right. It's just that Overflow community experts always have really ingenious ways of solving my questions. I'm afraid if I post my stupid code, they'll just modify my code to make it work when I could learn better more efficient ways I guess, sorry.

Comment: The first step to learning better and more efficient ways is to be able to come up with a way that works, **on your own**. This is why it is extremely important for you to try to solve the problem first. You learn very little if we just give you an answer that works.

Comment: ok thanks., will work on this and come back. How about any hints as to  what data structure to use? can i just use for loops and lists? should I look into hashmaps or anything else? thanks

Comment: Best solutions (more CPU/memory efficient) would not make use of a map; counts per letter can be stored in an array indexed by a simple transformation of the character value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class ColumnCharacterCount {
    private static final HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Character, Integer>> map =
            new HashMap<Integer, HashMap<Character, Integer>>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
        strings.add("ABSKSNFASLKFSAF");
        strings.add("LKGEROGNDFKGDFD");
        strings.add("GKDFLGSDFLGDFSJ");
        for (String str : strings) {
            for (int col = 0; col < str.length(); col++) {
                Character c = str.charAt(col);
                HashMap<Character, Integer> colMap = map.get(col);
                if (colMap == null) {
                    colMap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
                    map.put(col, colMap);
                }
                Integer charCounter = colMap.get(c);
                if (charCounter == null) {
                    charCounter = 0;
                }
                charCounter++;
                colMap.put(c, charCounter);
            }
        }
        Set<Entry<Integer, HashMap<Character, Integer>>> entrySet =
                map.entrySet();
        for (Entry<Integer, HashMap<Character, Integer>> entry : entrySet) {
            Integer key = entry.getKey();
            HashMap<Character, Integer> value = entry.getValue();
            System.out.printf("Column %2d has %s %n", key, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Column  0 has {G=1, A=1, L=1} 
Column  1 has {B=1, K=2} 
Column  2 has {D=1, G=1, S=1} 
Column  3 has {E=1, F=1, K=1} 
Column  4 has {S=1, R=1, L=1} 
Column  5 has {G=1, N=1, O=1} 
Column  6 has {F=1, G=1, S=1} 
Column  7 has {D=1, A=1, N=1} 
Column  8 has {D=1, F=1, S=1} 
Column  9 has {F=1, L=2} 
Column 10 has {G=1, K=2} 
Column 11 has {D=1, F=1, G=1} 
Column 12 has {D=1, F=1, S=1} 
Column 13 has {F=1, A=1, S=1} 
Column 14 has {D=1, F=1, J=1}
```